# How to split a list value in dataframe to multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data frame look like this:

[image]

this data frame contains only one column, but each value in that column contains a list, how to split this list and create a new data frame  contains 6 columns

Comment: can you please show me your data because i unable to see image on link.

Comment: I didn't get your question what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
pd.DataFrame([x])
```

Returns:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your column is `data`, you can use

```
df[['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6']] = pd.DataFrame([x for x in df.data])
```

E.g.

```
In [32]: df
Out[32]:
              data
0  [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
1  [3, 3, 4, 5, 5]

In [33]: df[['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5']] = pd.DataFrame([x for x in df.data])

In [34]: df
Out[34]:
              data c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
0  [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]  1  1  1  2  2
1  [3, 3, 4, 5, 5]  3  3  4  5  5
```